# Why xml autowire injection failed when getter method return a type different from the property?

Tags: spring, autowired, getter-setter

I wrote a snippet code to test autowire xml config. But I was getting the null pointer exception all the time which indicating that the field autowiring failed.

Contray to some other examples which can work, I found that the getter method return a type different from the field that is to be wired. Remove this getter method or modify the return type, then it works. 
But I don't know the reason. Why the getter method matters? I thought the setter method is used to wire, what about getter method ?

```
public class Department {

    private String departName;

    public String getDepartName() {
        return departName;
    }

    public void setDepartName(String departName) {
        this.departName = departName;
    }

}

public class Employee {
    private Department department;

//  1) below code will cause NPE
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department.getDepartName();
    }

//   2）below code works,  or just delete  1) code  works as well
    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(department.getDepartName());
    }
}
```

autowire xml config file looks like below:

```
<bean id="depart" class="com.kingdom.Department">
        <property name="departName" value="risk"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="employee" class="com.kingdom.Employee" autowire="byType">
    </bean>
```

and finally the main class:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

        Employee employee = (Employee) ctx.getBean("employee");
        employee.foo();
```

I expect the department can be autowired into the employee. But I got NPE.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.kingdom.Employee.foo (Employee.java:17)
    at com.kingdom.Main.main (Main.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

After modifying the return type , it works.

But is there anyone gotta know what's going on behind?  why getter method undermine the autowiring ?

Answer (score 1):

To use autowire , you have to enable it by including  `<context:annotation-config>` in `beans.xml`. You can also enable it by including `<context:component-scan>` , which will implicitly  enables the functionality of `<context:annotation-config>`.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

      <context:annotation-config>

      <bean> .... </bean>

</beans>
```

Then ,you have to annotate `@Autowired` on the `Employee` 's department setter to tell Spring to auto inject `Department` bean into the `Employee` bean. You can also annotate it on the department field or constructor.

```
public class Employee {

    @Autowired
    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
}
```

Since Spring 4.3, if the target bean only have one constructor, `@Autowired` is no longer need to be explicitly annotated on the target bean. However, if several constructors are available , `@Autowired` must be exist to teach the container how to inject the bean.

So , that mean if you do not want to annotate any `@Autowired` on the `Employee` , you have to make `Employee` only has one constructor :

```
public class Employee {

    public Employee(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
}
```

In both cases , `<context:annotation-config>` is still required to make the auto wiring to take effect.

Comment: I did NOT use @autowired annotation but rather the xml autowire config like autowire="byType".  I thought it does not need annotation-config.  Is it wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: see my update . If you do not use @autowired , you have to make the Employee has only one constructor.It only works after Spring 4.3 . But it still need  annotation-config

Comment: hi ken, as I said, when I modified the getter methode return type String to the bean class Department,  it works!  What I am concerning is that why the getter method matters?

Comment: getter does not matter. It works because the `Department` in `Employee` is always NULL due to your configuration such that `Department` cannot inject into `Employee`. The getter that works because if you does not access any property on the `NULL` department . The getter that do not work because you access some property on that `NULL` department and hence it has null pointer exception.